# Position recognition with Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-groovy, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I’m working on body position recognition using Kinect and openni_tracker, specifically the origin points (x, y and z) of the transformations (head, torso, elbow, hand…) given by the tracker. I have the points and now I pretend to work with them to recognize some specific positions of the body previously memorized.

I was told that Mahalanobis distance should work fine with this variables but I want to know if there is some other way to do it, some algorithm or a program already done.

I’m using ROS Groovy, so the MIT package is not an option, since I couldn’t make it work.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196007/position-recognition-with-kinect/) by [alexjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20309/alexjs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use the points x,y,z of each joint to do that

---

Originally posted by [idavico](https://answers.ros.org/users/20379/idavico/) with karma: 18 on 2014-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0